# spring ThreadPoolTaskExecutorto create new thread on each method call

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I have the following config for ThreadPoolTaskExecutor

```
 <bean id="threadPoolTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="25" />
    <property name="queueCapacity" value="30" />
</bean>
```

and I have 2 methods in my public class AdminService.

1. void triggerJob();
2. boolean executeSql(String sql);

How do i insert ThreadPoolTaskExecutor into triggerJob method so it creates new thread when executeSql is called inside first method.

Inside triggerjob i have loop that calls executeSql based on condition.

Do i need to create a private class that implements runnable so ThreadPoolTaskExecutor can execute this class or is it possible to create threads without runnable ?

My idea is something like this

```
@Autowired    
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor;

     void triggerJob(){
           for( Object k:Objects){
               if(k.equals(something){
                //here new thread to be created somehow 
                threadPoolTaskExecutor.execute(executeSql(k.getSql())
               }
           }
        }
```

Comment: Why do you need new thread? What's wrong with reusing threads? This is exactly what thread pool is intended for.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov  the task is executeSql to be executed in new Thread but i don't know much about threads so not sure how to implement this

Comment: *Why* it has to be a *new* Thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to do it you can use `org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`:

```
<bean id="simpleTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor">
   <property name="concurrencyLimit" value="25" />
</bean>
```

But creating a Java thread is expensive. It's generally recommended to reuse threads, even [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.html) say:

> NOTE: This implementation does not reuse threads! Consider a thread-pooling TaskExecutor implementation instead, in particular for executing a large number of short-lived tasks.